# Laravel-Ajax me envia el dato como null

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

Buenas recien estoy empezando con laravel, cuando envio el dato con ajax me sale array(0) en preview de la consola, cuando cambio el controlador a request->name me sale null, pero solamente es cuando lo envio por javascript, quito el ajax y el controlador me trae los input, que puede ser?

```
    var names = document.querySelector('#name');
    var phones = document.querySelector('#phone')
    let save = document.querySelector('#save');
    let getUrl = document.forms.createContact;
    let urls = getUrl.getAttribute('action')


    const saveDate = ( url, var1, var2) => {
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
        let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
        let data = {
            _token: token,
            name: var1.value,
            phone: var2.value
        }
        JSON.stringify(data)
        xhttp.open('post', url, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                console.log(xhttp.responseText)
                console.log(data.status, var1, var2)
            }
        }
        xhttp.send(data);
    }

    save.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        saveDate(urls, names, phones);

    });
```

```php
 public function insertDate(Request $request)
    {

        return var_dump($request->all());
    }
```

Route

```php
Route::resource('contactos', 'Contacts');

Route::post('/contactos', 'Contacts@insertDate')->name('contacts.insertDate');
```

[image: Respuesta del navegador por network]

[image: Vista del fomulario que evia por el controlador]

Comment: Lo único que veo es que después de `let data ...` no estás guardando el JSON en la variable, tendrías que hacer: `data = JSON.stringify(data)`. Desconozco si es correcto que envíes un JSON.

Comment: Buenas azeos ya lo solucione y en parte era eso pero igual ya lo habia asignado JSON.stringfy(data), lo tenia que colocar en el send.... y cambiar el formato de setRequestheader ....